# Is eating uncooked spaghetti dangerous?

Tags: food-safety, spaghetti

Sometimes I like to eat some (15 to 20 pieces) uncooked and dry spaghetti from the store as a snack.

Still, I am worried a little about salmonella and other such things, so my question:

How safe is eating uncooked spaghetti?

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about dried or fresh pasta? Dried pasta does not need to contain eggs but can be added for flavor. Amazon lists the ingredients to [Barilla pasta](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00338BWNU) as "Semolina, Durum Flour, Niacin, Iron (Ferrous Sulfate), Thiamine Mononitrate, Riboflavin, Folic Acid."

Comment: @clcto Edited the question to be clearer. Yes, dry spaghetti from the store and any reason not to eat them. Thanks

Comment: You might poke yourself in the eye with dry spaghetti. It should hydrate enough in your stomach so as not to poke holes in your intestines or anything horrific like that. No way you'll get a watermelon or squash growing out of you with spaghetti.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no;  in smaller quantities; no problem.  If you sit down in the morning and eat bowl daily; you will cause some serious long term issues.

1. Raw flour is full of lectins and phytates; which can pose a danger in higher amounts; damage the lower GI and cause IBS; other issues
2. Nutrient problems can develop from the raw flour intake at higher amounts
3. Bacteria standpoint; no problem; eat away.

As the comment mentioned; some fresh pasta could be harmful because of the raw egg.

Comment: Dried pasta is also pretty tough on your teeth.

Comment: Well, except for [flour mites](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/105892/what-is-the-tiny-white-self-moving-objects-on-pasta)...